# PHP: «Commands out of sync» if I mysqli::query() again after a call to a results-giving stored procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have a stored procedure in my db that returns all records in a table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE showAll()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM myTable;
END
```

The SP works just as expected. But, if I call it in a php script and then I try to query the database again, it always fail:

```
// $mysqli is a db connection

// first query:

if (!$t = $mysqli->query("call showAll()"))
    die('Error in the 1st query');

while ($r = $t->fetch_row()) {
    echo $r[0] . "<br>"; // this is ok
}

$t->free(); // EDIT (this doesn't help anyway)

// second query (does the same thing):

if (!$t = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from myTable"))
    die('Error in the 2nd query'); // I always get this error

while ($r = $t->fetch_row()) {
    echo $r[0] . "<br>";
}
```

Notable, if I swap the two queries (i.e. I call the stored procedure at the end) it works without any error. To close() the result before the second query doesn't help.
Some hints?

EDIT: mysqli::error() is: «Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now».

Comment: What happens if you call $t->free(); after your done processing the first query?

Comment: Have you checked `mysqli::error`?

Comment: I put a $t->free() after the first while loop but the behaviour doesn't change. mysqli::error is: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

Comment: why don't u just use `SELECT * FROM myTable;` ?????

Comment: That SP is just an example. The real scenery is more complex and I'd prefer to use SPs in order to keep data integrity.

Answer (score 5):

The comments on the php.net/manual entry for mysqli.query have been updated, and now include an answer for this. To summarize, call $mysqli->next_result() after $t->close(). Kudos to petrus.jvr!

Link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#102904

Answer (score 2):

@jymian, Your answer is not clear. Please express clearly.

After freeing result set using `$t->free()`,

Call `$mysqli->next_result()`.

The above call will prepare for next result set and you wont get out of sync errors.